# Using Google ID Token to Connect to non-Google services from a Google Workspace Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I have an API that I want my Google Workspace Add-on to connect to in an authenticated manner. I would to use the Google ID token as the login credential for the service as the users are already logged into Google. [This page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services) note that this should be possible, but does not gives an example or instructions on how to access the ID token from the add-on.

I believe the Server is able to verify the token by following the [instructions provided here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token).

Is [this how I access the Google ID Token](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getidentitytoken)?

```js
var idToken = ScriptApp.getIdentityToken();
```

along with adding the `openid` scope to the manifest?